# How to replace column with strings with look-up codes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, str-replace, gsub

Imagine that I have a dataframe or datatable with strings column where one row looks like this:

```
a1; b: b1, b2, b3; c: c1, c2, c3; d: d1, d2, d3, d4
```

and a look-up table with codes for mapping each of these strings. For example:

```
string code
a1     10
b1     20
b2     30
b3     40
c1     50
c2     60
...
```

I would like to have a mapping function that maps this string to code:

```
10; b: 20, 30, 40; c: 50, 60, 70; d: 80, 90, 100
```

I have a column of these strings in data.table/data.frame (more tha 100k) so any quick solution would be very appreciated.
Note that this string length is not always the same... for example in one row i can have strings `a` to `d`, in other `a` to `f`.

**EDIT**:

We got the solution for case above, however imagine I have a string like this:

```
a; b: peter, joe smith, john smith; c: luke, james, john smith
```

How to replace these knowning that `john smith` can have two different codes depending on whether it belongs to `b` or `c` category? 
Also, string can contain words with space in between them.

**EDIT 2**:

```
   string     code
    a          10
    peter      20
    joe smith  30
    john smith 40
    luke       50
    james      60
    john smith 70
...
```

The final solution is:

```
10; b: 20, 30, 40; c: 50, 60, 70
```

**EDIT 3** As suggested, I have opened a new question for next issue:
[How to replace repeated strings and space in-between with look-up codes in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60766304/how-to-replace-column-with-repeated-strings-and-space-in-between-with-look-up-co)

Comment: the `lookup` function frome the `epicalc` package might do what youa re after

Comment: what is the expected output for that new data

Comment: @akrun See Edit 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("([a-z]\\d+)", setNames(as.list(df1$code), df1$string), str1)
#[1] "10; b: 20, 30, 40; c: 50, 60, 70; d: 80, 90, 100, 110"
```

---

For the edited version

```
gsubfn("(\\w+ ?\\w+?)",  setNames(as.list(df2$code), df2$string), str2)
#[1] "a; b: 20, 30, 40; c: 50, 60, 40"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "a1; b: b1, b2, b3; c: c1, c2, c3; d: d1, d2, d3, d4"
df1 <- structure(list(string = c("a1", "b1", "b2", "b3", "c1", "c2", 
 "c3", "d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"), code = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 
 60L, 70L, 80L, 90L, 100L, 110L)), class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -11L))

str2 <- "a; b: peter, joe smith, john smith; c: luke, james, john smith"

df2 <- structure(list(string = c("a", "peter", "joe smith", "john smith", 
"luke", "james", "john smith"), code = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 
50L, 60L, 70L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! And what if I have words instead of letters? Also same words can map to different codes dependng on their position (whether they are in b or c group for example)?

Comment: @Makaroni regarding words, you can replace with. `[a-z]` with `\\w+`.  Not sure. about the other cases as this is based on your example

Comment: it worked when I replaced `[a-z]\\d+` with `\\w+`. Thank you!

Comment: One more thing, what should I use when I have words with space in it... for example `a b c` (as one string)? `\\w+` don't work in this case.

Comment: @Makaroni can you please update with all the cases as this regex is based on that pattern you showed

Comment: @Makaroni It is not. possible to have keys with duplicate values

Comment: As @akrun noted, you can't have duplicate keys but you can have keys by group (i.e. three columns in your lookup table i.e. group, string, code) if that's applicable to your problem.

Comment: @H1 I understand. Would it be possible to do it with additional column in look-up table that says group `a` `b` or `c`?

Comment: @Makaroni. that is possible.  then you need only a merge or join with key/val dataset and then do the replacement either with `gsubfn` or `str_replace_all`

Comment: @Makaroni - the edits mean the problem has moved beyond the scope of your original question.  It would be better to post a new question I think.

Comment: @Makaroni I think it is better to post as a new question bcz there are 3 answers based on your original question and if you change the post, it would also mean that the solutions are meaningless.

Comment: @H1 OK, sure I will.

Comment: @akrun new question posted.

Answer (score 2):

A much faster alternative would be to use `stringr::str_replace_all()`:

```
library(stringr)
library(gsubfn)

mystring <- "a1; b: b1, b2, b3; c: c1, c2, c3; d: d1, d2, d3, d4"
mystrings <- rep(mystring, 10000)

str_replace_all(mystrings, setNames(as.character(df$code), df$string))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(gsubfn = gsubfn("([a-z]\\d+)", setNames(as.list(df$code), df$string), mystrings),
                               stringr = str_replace_all(mystrings, setNames(as.character(df$code), df$string)), check = "equal", times = 50)

Unit: milliseconds
    expr        min         lq      mean     median         uq        max neval cld
  gsubfn 4846.19633 5584.54845 5923.5042 5939.49794 6261.29821 7479.04022    50   b
 stringr   29.01798   29.94274   31.6118   30.80002   31.72871   50.57533    50  a
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some base R solutions.

- **Approach 1:** use `Reduce`

```
res <- Reduce(function(x,k) gsub(df$string[k],df$code[k],x),
              c(s,as.list(1:nrow(df))))
```

such that

```
> res
[1] "10; b: 20, 30, 40; c: 50, 60, c3; d: d1, d2, d3, d4"
```

- **Approach 2:**
  define custom recursive function `f` to make it

```
f <- function(k) ifelse(k==0,s,gsub(df$string[k],df$code[k],f(k-1)))
res <- f(nrow(df))
```

such that

```
> res
[1] "10; b: 20, 30, 40; c: 50, 60, c3; d: d1, d2, d3, d4"
```

**DATA**

```
s <- "a1; b: b1, b2, b3; c: c1, c2, c3; d: d1, d2, d3, d4"
df <-structure(list(string = c("a1", "b1", "b2", "b3", "c1", "c2"), 
    code = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```